# Rewriterule for robots.txt

Tags: url-rewriting, robots.txt

I have a site like domain.com/view/nextdomain.com and I have robots who tries to access domain.com/view/nextdomain.com/robots.txt and I would like all the robots to access domain.com/robots.txt instead.

I don't know why this one doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule ^view/(.*)$/robots.txt robots.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

you only want to access main domain Robots.txt
remove sub folder robots.txt and move all rule of  sub folder domain.com/view/nextdomain.com/robots.txt to main domain.com/robots.txt

after move your rule update those one
Example:-

## domain.com/view/nextdomain.com/robots.txt has rul

`Disallow: /admin/`

then update code

`Disallow: domain.com/view/nextdomain.com/admin/`